# Postgresql: Get matched keywords

Tags: postgresql

I need to get matched keywords from the result in a separate column.

Table:

```
| name    | description       | info            |  matched        |
|---------|-------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
| Event1  | This will be great| great experience|great,experience |
| Event2  | great experience  | great thinking  |great,experience |
| Event3  | Great match       | think           |great            |
```

Array:
{great,experience}

With this array I want the matched keywords as shown above

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select e.name, 
       e.description,
       (select string_agg(distinct lower(m.word), ',') 
        from regexp_split_to_table(concat_ws(' ', e.description, e.info), '\s') as m(word) 
        where lower(m.word) = any(array['great','experience']))
from events e;
```

But that won't be very fast

Online example: http://rextester.com/UHAU52066